# Turn off Excel Compatibility Mode

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I experimented with compatibility mode in Excel 365, now I can't turn it off, every new workbook opens in Compatibility Mode.

Crawled the web for an answer, but only found how to save a particular Book as normal. I want it by default to be in normal mode whenever I open a new workbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `File`->`Options`->`Save`, do you have it set to save files in "Excel Workbook" format?
[image]